# ValueError when apply function to data frame in python-pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a very simple data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.full((6), 1))
```

Now I am going to define a function that generate a numpy array with random length and add the given value to the tail:

```
import numpy as np
def func(row):
    l = np.full((np.random.random_integer(5)), 1)
    return np.hstack(l, row)
```

When I try to apply the function to `df` to get a `2-D array`:

```
df.apply(func, axis=1),
```

I got such an error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 2), indices imply (6, 1)
```

Do you know what is the problem and how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `random_integet` is not a np function can you update your code with something that runs

Comment: @EdChum Sorry, I have already correct the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you want `np.random.random_integers`, secondly `hstack` takes a tuple so pass a tuple, thirdly you need to return something that it can align with so in this case a `Series`:

```
In [213]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.full((6), 1))
def func(row):
    l = np.full((np.random.random_integers(5)), 1)
    return pd.Series(np.hstack((l, row)))

In [214]:    
df.apply(func, axis=1)

Out[214]:
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Note that I get a ton of warnings about the above:

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:301: FutureWarning: in the future, full(3, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:301: FutureWarning: in the future, full(2, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:301: FutureWarning: in the future, full(1, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:301: FutureWarning: in the future, full(4, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:301: FutureWarning: in the future, full(5, 1) will return an array of dtype('int32')
  format(shape, fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
```

To get a np array from a df call attribute `values`:

```
df.apply(func, axis=1).values
```

Comment: Thanks for your magic answer! But can I transfer it to numpy 2-D array or matrix? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by editing your question with desired output

Comment: I have edited the question already. Actually I just want the output is a numpy array instead of series. Thanks.

Comment: So you want `df.apply(func, axis=1).values`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!